# Target Only the Tab of TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, tabcontrol

#### The Problem:

I am creating a drag/drop interface that allows for moving items within a tab as well as from one tab to another. Right now I have the following `Style` that allows me to target the `Label` within a `TabItem`. Because of a conflict with a `ResourceDictionary`, I want to add the `Event` through the code behind. The problem is if I add the `Event` to the `TabItem` then it triggers not only on the tab itself but the contents of the tab.

#### The Question:

How would I go about wiring up the event in the code behind for the following?

```
<Style
    x:Key="DragDropTi"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}"
    TargetType="TabItem"> 
    <Setter
        Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label
                    Foreground="White"
                    Content="{Binding}">
                    <Label.Style>
                        <Style
                            TargetType="Label">
                            <EventSetter
                                Event="Drop"
                                Handler="TabItemDrop" />
                            <Setter
                                Property="AllowDrop"
                                Value="True" />
                        </Style>
                    </Label.Style>
                </Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being easier than anticipated. I just had to set the `MenuItem.Header`as a `Label` instead of a string of the name and attach the `Event` to the `Label`

```
Label header = new Label();
header.Content = "Tab Name";
header.AllowDrop = true;
header.Drop += new DragEventHandler(TabItemDrop);

TabItem tabItem = new TabItem();
tabItem.Header = header;
```